# how to store a subset of a data frame in another data frame based on some conditions

Tags: r

I have a csv file which has few observations based on 2 cities. i have added a city with as 1 and 2 to differentiate. i want to create 2 separate data frames on different cities. 
I have used 2 approaches.

1. subset function  `y <- subset(x, x$code == 1)`
2. indexing approach `y <- x[x$code ==1, ]`

Both the statements were executed successfully but when i enter y data frame , i get only the column names as the output with 0 rows.

Can anyone help me with an alternate method or point out the error in approach i am using?

```
  Code       city  pickup_datetime pickup_date Hour          Hour range
1    1 Chandigarh 24-03-2016 00:00  24-03-2016    0 00:00:00 - 01:00:00
2    1 Chandigarh 24-03-2016 01:45  24-03-2016    1 01:00:00 - 02:00:00
3    1 Chandigarh 24-03-2016 02:00  24-03-2016    2 02:00:00 - 03:00:00
4    1 Chandigarh 24-03-2016 03:15  24-03-2016    3 03:00:00 - 04:00:00
5    2   Ludhiana 24-03-2016 00:45  24-03-2016    0 00:00:00 - 01:00:00
6    2   Ludhiana 24-03-2016 01:46  24-03-2016    1 01:00:00 - 02:00:00
7    2   Ludhiana 24-03-2016 02:30  24-03-2016    2 02:00:00 - 03:00:00
```

data.frame':    48 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ Code           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ city           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Chandigarh","Ludhiana": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ pickup_datetime: Factor w/ 43 levels "24-03-2016 00:00",..: 1 3 5 7 9 10 11 14 15 18 ...
 $ pickup_date    : Factor w/ 1 level "24-03-2016": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Hour           : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ Hour.range     : Factor w/ 24 levels "00:00:00 - 01:00:00",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

Comment: It's likely that `x$code` has no elements equal to `1`. We need to see your data to investigate further.

Comment: is there a way i can share the data with you here.

Comment: You can paste some data into the question, or alternatively post it onto a data-sharing site like Github and provide the link.

Comment: @bgoldst or simulate a dataset that mimics users' dataset.

Comment: i have added few rows of my data set in the question.

Comment: Can you also paste `str(x)`?

Comment: data.frame': 48 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ Code           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ city           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Chandigarh","Ludhiana": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ pickup_datetime: Factor w/ 43 levels "24-03-2016 00:00",..: 1 3 5 7 9 10 11 14 15 18 ...
 $ pickup_date    : Factor w/ 1 level "24-03-2016": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Hour           : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ Hour.range     : Factor w/ 24 levels "00:00:00 - 01:00:00",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

Comment: You have the column name as `Code` and not `code`

Comment: What makes you think this long output would be suitable for comments over your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use

```
y <- subset(x, Code==1)
```

as the column name is "Code" and not "code".  Just note that there is no need for `x$Code` inside the `subset`.

---

If we need to create two datasets for each "Code", we can `split` the `data.frame` to a `list` of `data.frame`s.

```
lst <- split(x, x$Code)
```

If this is needed as individual data.frames in the global environment,

```
list2env(setNames(lst, paste0("y", names(lst))), 
                       envir= .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y <- subset(x, x$Code == 1)

y <- x[x$Code ==1, ]
```

Comment: Also you may want to try using RStudio, it has an autocompletion feature for variable names and it is difficult to get this bug with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
y<-data.frame(subset(x[x$Code==1,]))
```

Where, x--parent data frame, y--data frame with only code=1